# Razor Pages calling asp-page-handler method from javascript validation function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a button with client side validation function

```
<button type="submit" title="Submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="return OnSubmitValidate()">
                        Submit
                    </button>
```

i want to call asp-page-handler method inside this javascript function .Currently im using AJAX method ,but its not firing the method.

```
function OnSubmitValidate() {
        
        var RequestType = document.getElementById("DrpDwnRequestType");
        var RequestTypeValue = RequestType.options[RequestType.selectedIndex].value;
        alert(RequestTypeValue);
        if ((RequestTypeValue == "") || (RequestTypeValue == null)) {
            document.getElementById("ErrRequestType").innerHTML = "Please select Request Type";
            return false;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: rootPath + "/RequestForm?handler=Submit",
            dataType: "json"
        });        
    }
```

Edit:Submit Handler

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSubmitAsync()
        {
            
            
            BillType = new SelectList(_context.BillType.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "BillTypes", "BillTypes");



            var requestexist = await _context.RequestFormMaster.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.RequestID == RequestFormMaster.RequestID);

            RequestAlreadyExist = requestexist;
            if (RequestAlreadyExist != null)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            else
            {
                RequestFormMaster.RequestID = RequestFormMaster.RequestID.Trim();
                
                RequestFormMaster.LastModifiedBy = HttpContext.Session.GetString("firstname") + " " + HttpContext.Session.GetString("lastname");
                RequestFormMaster.LastModifiedTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;

                _context.Entry(RequestFormMaster).State = EntityState.Added;
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                TempData["ReqSubmitted"] = "Submitted";
                
                
                if (ReqSupportingFiles != null || ReqSupportingFiles.Count > 0)
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (IFormFile upload in ReqSupportingFiles)
                    {
                        i++;
                        // Upload file to server folder
                        string ext = Path.GetExtension(upload.FileName).ToLower();
                        if ((ext == ".ppt") || (ext == ".pptx") || (ext == ".xls") || (ext == "xlsx"))
                        {
                            var filesave = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Documents", foldername, i + "_" + upload.FileName);
                            using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filesave))
                            {
                                await upload.CopyToAsync(stream);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                return RedirectToPage("/RequestSummary");
            }
            //return Page();

        }
```

I want to submit this entire form . need to insert form data to table.Anyhelp would be appreciated

Comment: Please add the code of the Submit handler. What are you submitting here? There is no data sent to the handler.

Comment: @Steve I have added the submit handler. I need to submit the form before that im checking mandatory fields using javascript function since i have several conditions for mandatory check i didnt use required dataannotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass entire form data to handler,here is a demo:

Model:

```
public class FormModel
        {
            public string RequestType { get; set; }
            public string Test { get; set; }

        }
```

view:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
    <select id="DrpDwnRequestType" name="RequestType">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <input id="Test" name="Test"/>
    <input type="button" title="Submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="OnSubmitValidate()" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

js:

```
function OnSubmitValidate() {

        var RequestType = document.getElementById("DrpDwnRequestType");
        var RequestTypeValue = RequestType.options[RequestType.selectedIndex].value;
        alert(RequestTypeValue);
        if ((RequestTypeValue == "") || (RequestTypeValue == null)) {
            document.getElementById("ErrRequestType").innerHTML = "Please select Request Type";
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "?handler=Submit",
                headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
                
            });
            window.location.href = "xxx";
        }

        
    }
```

handler:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSubmitAsync(FormModel formModel)
{  
     ...        
}
```

ajax with post request in razor page need to add `RequestVerificationToken` to header,and ajax call handler will not redirect to `RequestSummary`,so you can try to use `window.location.href` to redirect in js.
result:
[image]